# LQR control effort / control bandwidth relationship

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, linear-systems

I'm working with a linear system, having given matrices A and B
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -0.9 & 0 \end{array}\right]$$

$$B = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0  \\ 2 \end{array}\right]$$

assume we have full state and no feedtrough matrix $D$ so
$$C = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$
$$D = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0  \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$$

I want to design an LQR feedback controller for this system: the LQR theory states that by increasing the elements on the diagonal of $Q$ I will make the corresponding state errors smaller and by increasing the scalar $R$ I will change the control effort, and this tradeoff will be reflected in the $K$ matrix
$$K = lqr(A,B,Q,R)$$
However, my question is the following: is it possible to increase the bandwidth without increasing the control effort? I'd like a more reactive system, but I have saturation limits to be taken into account.

Note: I know that MPC would be probably better but it's more to understand the control efforts / control bandwidth relationship in LQR controllers.